# Call RecognizerIntent from service

Tags: android, service, speech-recognition

I am working on an Android service.
I need to call RecognizerIntent from a service in order to use in the service the recognized text. I have no startActivityForResult() method in Service class so I have problem understanding how to achieve this task. Is it possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I do not believe it is possible. After all, there is no UI from a service, and the `RecognizerIntent` needs a UI in order to function.

Comment: and trying to call an activity that implements startActivityForResults() that calls, through aidl, the service?

Comment: Services cannot call `startActivityForResult()`, only activities can.

Comment: yes indeed service will call startActivity() starting an activity that implements startActivityForResult() and then will set information on service through aidl. Could it work?

Comment: You already have an activity visible on-screen, I hope. Having a service pop up an activity in the middle of the user doing something else is very impolite -- and since your goal is to effectively record their voice, it also raises privacy issues.